# Who views moderator flags right now?

Tags: support

As far as I'm aware, we do not yet have any moderators here on ELL. That being the case, when I flag a question as "needs ♦ moderator attention", who (if anyone) is notified?

Comment: See also: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/391/moderator-pro-tem-announcement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Stack Exchange community team keeps an eye on them as far as I know. Robert Cartaino has been floating around here and I assume other members of [the team](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) do too.

Comment: Correct and correct. Also worth mentioning is that we will be appointing moderators from your community, per the process outlined in **[Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

Comment: Thanks Deco!  And @RobertCartaino, thanks! I actually did know that, but was curious what happened in the meantime.  Thanks for your response here and on other questions, and for keeping an eye on our site!

Answer (score 5):

The only users who have access to the moderator menu are part of the Stack Exchange staff; to be exact, only those who have a diamond close to their name have privileges equivalent to the ones a moderator has (but their privileges are not limited to that).